# Connection Failed [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver] Can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql

when i am creating DSN name for remote i am getting this error

> Connection Failed [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver] Can't connect to
>   MySQL

Comment: Hi pardhu, welcome to SO.  You might like to have a read of the [faq] and the section on [ask].  Your question contains *far* too little detail for it to be answered in its current form.

Comment: You have to provide more details. Info you have given is not at all enough.

Comment: Also, I'm removing the [tag:sql-server] tag (as that relates to a different product entirely, Microsoft SQL Server).